# Odd substitution behaviour in perl substitution of rtf file

Tags: regex, perl, rtf

I am trying to use the perl module "RTF::Writer" for strings of text that must be a mix of formats. This is proving more complicated than I anticipated. I am just trying a test at the moment with:

`$rtf->paragraph( \'\b', "Name: $name, le\cf1 ng\cf0 th $len" );`

but this writes:

```
{\pard
\b
Name: my_name, le\'061 ng\'060 th 7
\par}
```

where `\'061` should be `\cf1` and `\'060` should be `\cf0`.

I then tried to remedy this with a perl 1-liner:

`perl -pi -e "s/\'06/\cf/g"`

but this made things worse, I do not know what `"\^F"` represents in vi, but that is what it shows.

It did not matter if I escaped the backslashes or not.

Can anyone explain this behavior, and what to do about it?

Can anyone suggest how to get the RTF::Writer to create the file as desired from the start?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` is a special character in double-quoted string literals. If you want a string that contains `\`, you need to use `\\` in the literal. To create the string `\cf1`, you need to use `"\\cf1"`. (`"\cf"` means Ctrl-F, which is to say the byte `06`.)

Alternatively, `\` is only special if followed by `\` or a delimiter in single-quoted string literals. So the string `\cf1` could also be created from `'\cf1'`.

Both produce the string you want, but they don't produce the document you want. That's because there's a second problem.

When you pass a string to RTF::Writer, it's expected to be text to render. But you are passing a string you wanted included as is in the final document. You need to pass a reference to a string if you want to provide raw RTF. `\'...'`, `\"..."` and `\$str` all produce a reference to a string.

Fixed:

```
use RTF::Writer qw( );

my $name = "my_name";

my $rtf = RTF::Writer->new_to_file("greetings.rtf");
$rtf->prolog( 'title' => "Greetings, hyoomon" );
$rtf->paragraph( \'\b', "Name: $name, le", \'\cf1', "ng", \'\cf0', "th".length($name));
$rtf->close;
```

Output from the call to `paragraph`:

```
{\pard
\b
Name: my_name, le\cf1
ng\cf0
th7
\par}
```

---

Note that I didn't use the following because it would be [code injection bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection):

```
$rtf->paragraph(\("\\b Name: $name, le\\cf1 ng\\cf0 th".length($name)));
```

Don't pass text such as the contents of `$name` using `\...`; use that for raw RTF only.

Comment: Thanks ~ of course! I knew that but screwed it up. After escaping the backslash it still did not work, but you did put me in a direction that I could make work. I made a new string variable, concatenating my previous variable with '\cf1' and '\cf0' (single quotes). It still did not work right out of the gate with RTF::Writer, but I could then fix the erroneous rtf code with the 1-liner.

Comment: Added to my answer

Comment: Great - and thanks for the explanation. Problem Solved! By using the reference to the string it worked as it should. So I do not have to resort to trying to rectify errors in the rtf post-closing.